# Bootstrap: force image height to height of row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page layout where two `div`s are aligned next to each other inside a row. One column contains a text of variable length, and the second one contains an image.

The markup is basically the following:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span6">
      <img src="picture.png">
   </div>
   <div class="span6">
     text<br>text
   </div>
</div>
```

What I intend is the following: The size of the image should be reduced such that it is exactly as high as the column containing the text. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HjcV/) for clarification.

Is there any way to achieve this only with CSS? As far as I know, the `object-fit` CSS3 command would be what I need, but unfortunately it is not well supported (yet?), see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit). Setting the image as `background-image` of the surrounding `div` is not an option, since the `img` is needed by a jQuery-plugin afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

**-EDIT-**

See this updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2HjcV/3/
Which makes use of `background-size:contain`. More info on this here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size

---

OP,

Try moving the `<div class="span6">` which holds the image into the `<div class="span6">` which holds the text.

[Fiddle updated here](http://jsfiddle.net/2HjcV/1/)

Comment: It does not work, the image height is still greater then the height of the text.

Comment: Well, in my browsers (Webkit based) the height of the image is still greater than the height of the 4 lines of text.

Comment: Hm, not the case for me: [http://oi48.tinypic.com/2elqk5l.jpg](http://oi48.tinypic.com/2elqk5l.jpg). Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: In the updated version (revision 3) of the jsfiddle it works, but only because the image is set as a background image which I unfortunately cannot do in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply no, this is not possible with CSS only at least if you want to do something cross browser. You have a fluid layout and I believe that by default bootstrap has the css rule for img at max-width: 100% forcing it to be bound by its parent container and respecting the aspect ratio. 
You will need Javascript to know the height of the text div and dynamically add that height to the image, or wrap them both in a parent container with a fixed height and apply max-height: 100% on the image and overflow: scroll or hidden on the div.
Hope it helps,
Cheers